# How to get image value of Datagridview Image Cell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewimagecolumn

I have an datagridview with **play** image ImageColumn and if user click play icon then **CellClick** Event set "**Stop**" image from Resources.

```
Private Sub dg1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dg1.CellClick
    dg1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value = New Bitmap(app1.My.Resources.stop)
End Sub
```

But i need get user what image click (Play or Stop)
How to get datagridview image name for Cellclick event?
I tried

```
dg1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
```

But returned "**System.Drawing.Image**" value i need image value.
Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks for interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would get the image. First check if the cell you click is of type `DataGridViewImageCell`. If it is, try casting the `Value` property as whatever image format you are expecting.

```
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewImageColumn());

        BitMap bitMap = new BitMap(5,5); // or however you get it from resources
        bitMap.Tag = "Play"; // Put the name of the image here

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(bitMap); 
    }

    void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var dgv = sender as DataGridView;
        if (dgv == null)
            return;

        var imageCell = dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] as DataGridViewImageCell;
        if (imageCell == null)
            return;

        var image = imageCell.Value as Bitmap;
        if (image == null)
            return;

        string name = image.Tag as String;           
    }
```

Alternatively, you could save the bitmap as a class level variable:

```
    Bitmap playBitmap = New Bitmap(app1.My.Resources.play);
    Bitmap stopBitmap = New Bitmap(app1.My.Resources.stop);
```

then in the `CellClick` method:

```
    void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var dgv = sender as DataGridView;
        if (dgv == null)
            return;

        var imageCell = dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] as DataGridViewImageCell;
        if (imageCell == null)
            return;

        if(imageCell.Value == playBitmap) 
        {

        }
        else if (imageCell.Value == stopBitmap)
        {

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for help but app is returned System.Drawing.Bitmap value of image cell, i need image current name.

Comment: like the name of the resource?